# ZF2 injecting InputFilter into Fieldset not working automatically

Tags: php, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm building a small application with ZF2 and Doctrine2. Setting it up in such a way as to have a lot of reusable code and technique. However, getting stumped by the fact that my `InputFilter` is not automatically injected into the `Fieldset` that it should get associated to.

I've confirmed that the Form that uses the `Fieldset` works (without the `InputFilter`). The `InputFilter` is also visible as present during debugging.

The question then, what am I doing wrong and how to fix having a separate `InputFilter`, coupled to a `Fieldset` in ZF2?

---

Sidenotes:

1 - I am aware that by using the `InputFilterInterface` I could have the `InputFilter` inside of the `Fieldset` class with the `getInputFilterSpecification()` function. However, as I'm trying to keep it DRY and reusable, it wouldn't do to have to copy it if I were to create an API that needs to use the `Entity` and `InputFilter`, but can only have the latter coupled with a `Fieldset`.

2 - A lot of Abstract classes are used, where used I'll indicate in the snippets what they have that's relevant

**3 - The problem line is in `CustomerFieldsetFactory.php`**

=========================================================================

Entity: `Customer.php`

```
/**
 * Class Customer
 * @package Customer\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="customers")
 */
class Customer extends AbstractEntity //Contains $id
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $name;
}
```

Form: `CustomerForm.php`

```
class CustomerForm extends AbstractForm
{
    public function __construct($name = null, array $options)
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $options); // Adds CSRF
    }

    public function init()
    {
        $this->add([
            'name' => 'customer',
            'type' => CustomerFieldset::class,
            'options' => [
                'use_as_base_fieldset' => true,
            ],
        ]);

        //Call parent initializer. Check in parent what it does.
        parent::init(); //Adds submit button if not in form
    }
}
```

Fieldset: `CustomerFieldset.php`

```
class CustomerFieldset extends AbstractFieldset //Contains EntityManager property and constructor requirement (as we're managing Doctrine Entities here)
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->add([ //For now id field is here, until InputFilter injection works
            'name' => 'id',
            'type' => Hidden::class,
            'attributes' => [
                'id' => 'entityId',
            ],
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'name',
            'type' => Text::class,
            'options' => [
                'label' => _('Name'),
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

InputFilter: `CustomerInputFilter.php`

```
class CustomerInputFilter extends AbstractInputFilter
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'name',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => [
                ['name' => StringTrim::class],
                ['name' => StripTags::class],
            ],
            'validators' => [
                [
                    'name' => StringLength::class,
                    'options' => [
                        'min' => 3,
                        'max' => 255,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Above the classes. Below the Factories**

FormFactory: `CustomerFormFactory.php`

```
class CustomerFormFactory implements FactoryInterface, MutableCreationOptionsInterface
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $options;

    /**
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function setCreationOptions(array $options)
    {
        //Arguments checking removed
        $this->options = $options;
    }

    /**
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface|ControllerManager $serviceLocator
     * @return CustomerForm
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $serviceManager = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();

        $form = new CustomerForm($this->options['name'], $this->options['options']);

        $form->setTranslator($serviceManager->get('translator'));

        return $form;
    }
}
```

FieldsetFactory: `CustomerFieldsetFactory.php`

```
class CustomerFieldsetFactory implements FactoryInterface, MutableCreationOptionsInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;

    public function setCreationOptions(array $options)
    {
        //Argument checking removed

        $this->name = $options['name'];
    }

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $serviceManager = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();

        $fieldset = new CustomerFieldset($serviceManager->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager'), $this->name);

        $fieldset->setHydrator(new DoctrineObject($serviceManager->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default'), false));
        $fieldset->setObject(new Customer());
        $fieldset->setInputFilter($serviceManager->get('InputFilterManager')->get(CustomerInputFilter::class));

        //RIGHT HERE! THE LINE ABOVE IS THE ONE THAT DOES NOT WORK!!!

        return $fieldset;
    }
}
```

InputFilterFactory: `CustomerInputFilterFactory.php`

```
class CustomerInputFilterFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $repository = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()
            ->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')
                ->getRepository(Customer::class);

        return new CustomerInputFilter($repository);
    }
}
```

Config: `module.config.php`

```
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        CustomerController::class => CustomerControllerFactory::class,
    ],
],
'form_elements' => [
    'factories' => [
        CustomerForm::class => CustomerFormFactory::class,
        CustomerFieldset::class => CustomerFieldsetFactory::class,
    ],
],
'input_filters' => [
    'factories' => [
        CustomerInputFilter::class => CustomerInputFilterFactory::class,
    ],
],
'service_manager' => [
    'invokables' => [
        CustomerControllerService::class => CustomerControllerService::class,
    ],
],
```

---

I am hoping one of you can help me out here.

---

**EDIT: Update with actual error**

The following line in the `CustomerFieldset.php` (above) triggers the error.

```
$fieldset->setInputFilter($serviceManager->get('InputFilterManager')->get(CustomerInputFilter::class));
```

The error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Customer\Fieldset\CustomerFieldset::setInputFilter() in D:\htdocs\server-manager\module\Customer\src\Customer\Factory\CustomerFieldsetFactory.php on line 57
```

[image: Debug snippet]

As seen in the above snippet, the InputFilter (and it's Factory) are known the the `InputFilterManager`.

The error states it does not know the `getInputFilter()` function on the Fieldset. Which is correct in a way, it doesn't exist. The question then is, how to have the function exist so that injecting the InputFilter will work, or how to bind this InputFilter to the Fieldset?

---

**EDIT 2: Update based on Wilt's answer**
Added `use InputFilterAwareTrait` to Abstract class `AbstractInputFilter` to create following (from answer):

```
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareTrait;

abstract class AbstractFieldset extends Fieldset
{
    use InputFilterAwareTrait;
    // ... Other code
}
```

Turns out that I had another mistake in the (original) code above as well: 
In file `module.config.php` the `input_filters` should've been `input_filter_specs`. This was (after using the Trait) a `Invalid Factory registered` error (titled `ServiceNotCreatedException`).

The following might be of use to someone, the Factory to create a Fieldset with Hydrator, Object and Inputfilter has the following `createService()` function:

```
public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
{
    /** @var ServiceLocator $serviceManager */
    $serviceManager = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
    /** @var CustomerRepository $customerRepository */
    $customerRepository = $serviceManager->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')->getRepository(Customer::class);

    $fieldset = new CustomerFieldset($serviceManager->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager'), $this->name);
    $fieldset->setHydrator(new DoctrineObject($serviceManager->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default'), false));
    $fieldset->setObject(new Customer());
    $fieldset->setInputFilter($serviceManager->get('InputFilterManager')->get(CustomerInputFilter::class, $customerRepository));

    return $fieldset;
}
```

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: You have provided allot of information but not really explained the actual *error*. Is the `CustomerInputFilter` found by the input filter manger? Do you execute any code in `CustomerInputFilterFactory`?

Comment: @PurpleHexagon No not yet. Current working around it with `InputFilterProviderInterface` on the fieldset and having the specifcations in a `getInputFilterSpecification` function.

Comment: @AlexP I've updated the question (at the bottom ;) ) to clearly illustrate where the problem occurs, that I've debugged the vars and understand the error. Just don't know how to fix the error ;) Both InputFilter and InputFilterFactory are registered in the manager. However no code gets executed in the InputFilterFactory. `->get('CustomerInputFilter')` actually returns: `An exception was raised while creating "Customer\Fieldset\CustomerFieldset"; no instance returned`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is lots of information added to your question. I'd suggest you try to narrow down your question in the future. Read more on the guidelines for a good question here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Zend framework provides a `InputFilterAwareTrait` with both the `setInputFilter` and `getInputFilter` methods. You can easily implement/use this trait inside your `CustomerFieldset` class:

```
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareTrait;

class CustomerFieldset extends AbstractFieldset
{
    use InputFilterAwareTrait;

    //...remaining code

}
```

In case you want the inputfilter in all classes that extend your abstract `AbstractFieldset` class you could also decide to add the trait there:

```
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareTrait;

class AbstractFieldset
{
    use InputFilterAwareTrait;

    //...remaining code

}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked out! Had some follow up errors due to incorrect config. Edited question to show those (as they came from all the code I provided). Also provided whole `createService()` function for those that follow. Was not aware of the `InputFilterAwareTrait`, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

See the following question: [How to validate nested fieldsets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17313106/2220338). Fieldsets don't contain InputFilters but you should extend your base InputFilter of your form.

Create an InputFilter for each Fieldset and add them, with the same name as your fieldset, to your InputFilter of your form. As seen within the answer of the other question I linked.

If you don't want to do this you might consider working with InputSpecification.